# dynamic value pass to applet based on dropdown value selection

Tags: applet

I have to pass value dynamically  to applet so that it can pick correct xml from resource based on the value selected from the dropdown .

```
<applet code="com.vaannila.utility.dynamicTreeApplet.class" archive="./appletjars/dynamictree.jar, ./appletjars/prefuse.jar" width ="1000" height="500" >
</applet>
```

How can i do that .

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this by writing a public method in your applet
let's assume

```
void setXmlName(String xmlName);
```

you can access this method from java script .. for example this java script method

```
function updateXmlName(value){
 /* Get an object of the applet .. make sure the at 'id' attribute has the 'myappletid' value. */
 var myApplet = documents.applets["myappletid"];
 myApplet.setXmlName(value); 
}
```

update your dropbox HTML

```
<select id="optionList" onchange="updateXmlName(document.getElementById('optionList').value);>
```

I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose a value from dropdown and then send it to the page with applet then used simple `<param>` tag ([as described here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/param.html)). If you want to do it dynamically, then you can invoke java methods via javascript as described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html).